# Парсинг сайта Яндекс

Tags: python, парсер

Всем добрый день. Возник вопрос при парсинге новостей из Яндекса. https://yandex.ru/
Подскажите, как спарсить именно блок новостей? Вот код, но почему-то не работает.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.encoding = 'utf8'
    return r.text


def get_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    head = soup.find('div', class_='news__header widget__content').find('span', class_="news__item-content ").get_text
    print(head)


data = get_link(get_html('https://yandex.ru/'))
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно распарсить сайт Яндекса (если поможет):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://yandex.ru'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# Ищет все новости и записывает в переменную
news = soup.find_all('a', class_='home-link list__item-content list__item-content_with-icon '
                                 'home-link_black_yes')

# Выводит текст каждой новости (всего их 10)
for link in news:
    print(link.text)
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, когда использовать метод find_all и find? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Метод обхода дерева findAll начинает с заданной точки и ищет все объекты Tag и NavigableString, соответствующие заданным критериям. 

Метод find почти в точности совпадает с findAll, за исключением того, что он ищет первое вхождение искомого объекта, а не все.

Вот тут почитать можно: http://wiki.python.su/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/BeautifulSoup

Comment: Понял, спасибо!